# King wall heater - fan works but no heat

Tags: walls, heater

The other day our King wall heater stopped working.  The fan spins but no heat.  I took it apart and cleaned it, I also reset the breaker and the unit itself (via the instructions to turn off the thermostat for 10seconds).  However nothing has fixed it.

During cleaning there seemed to be some bits of the heating coil so Im thinking that somehow that broke.

Is there any way to replace just the coils?  I couldn't find them anywhere.

Barring replacement of just the coil I need to replace the whole unit, but I dont understand these stickers and what model I actually have installed.

This seems like the right replacement model but the measurements dont line up (am I missing something)?
[Amazon replacement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PS6NP8)

damaged coils:
[image]

the measurements I read are 11.5" x 8.75"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe the Amazon dimensions (10" x 13.5") refer to the grille dimensions, which is larger than the actual unit. The manual (https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/docresources/12462/25/252011.pdf) has a diagram that confirms that suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally heard back from King today (very helpful once you get a response).  It answers my questions.
also i verified it was the heating "element" by taking it out of a working one, so i only had to replace that!!!

response from King (manufacturer):

> Yes this is our W series https://www.king-electric.com/pdfs/W_WEB.pdf
>   These have a 1 year warranty.
>
> Here is the element
>   http://www.morelectricheating.com/default.aspx?page=item+detail&itemcode=KINGELECTRIC50303&catlist=1363&parent=7983
>
> Its best to go by our catalog for dimensions. Other sites are popular
>   for getting the diminsions wrong. The dimensions have been the same
>   since the unit came out in 1992
>
> Here is the unit you need
>   http://www.morelectricheating.com/default.aspx?page=item+detail&itemcode=KINGELECTRIC12743&catlist=262&parent=1366